# SQL query syntax when dealing with multi-valued fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I am constructing a SQL Developer query to retrieve records with a specified status'. Multiple values can also be selected. How can I update my query to include records with multiple "Status" values? which are semicolon delimited i.e. Off; Pending

Here is my query which only returns records with a singular status:

```
Select * from LOGS where Status= 'Off' or Status = 'Pending' or Status = 'ON';
```

Comment: How can status be 'Off' AND 'Pending' AND 'On'?

Comment: Please add sample data and the desired result.

Comment: What do you mean - do you have a column STATUS and the values can be 'Off' or 'Pending' but they can also be 'Off;Pending'? (Or, with a space after the semicolon?) If so, why can't you add `or Status = 'Off; Pending'`? So perhaps that is not what you mean? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from LOGS where Status= 'Off' and Status = 'Pending' and Status = 'ON';
```

you must mean OR´s instead of AND´s, the same column cannot have those 3 values on the same row

```
   Select * from LOGS where Status= 'Off' or Status = 'Pending' or Status = 'ON';
```

this change will allow you to get every LOGS row where any of those 3 status is valid

if you mean that status can have multiple values like "Off; Pending;ON" all you have to do is:

```
 Select * from LOGS where Status like '%Off%' or Status like '%Pending%' or Status like '%ON%';
```

this means "bring every status that have Off on it, even if it is Offline, 123Off123" and so on to the other cases, so be carefull on your status

Comment: how do I now handle a case of multiple selected values?

Comment: is your question answered? i´m confused. can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Select * from LOGS
where
    concat('; ', Status,'; ') like '%; Off; %' or
    concat('; ', Status,'; ') like '%; Pending; %' or 
    concat('; ', Status,'; ') like '%; On; %'    ;
```

or perhaps better

```
Select * from LOGS
where
    REGEXP_LIKE (concat('; ', Status,'; '),'; Off; |; Pending; |; On; ')
```

Comment: '%Pending%' will not accept 'End', its case sensitive

Comment: Will that not depend on collation? I'm not so familiar with Oracle (thinking of SQL-Server)

Comment: i was answering for the sql case, i can´t test it now but i´m convinced it will not accept. if it does, i´m glad to hear. your solution with REGEX seems good but complex.

Comment: found something else, in your first answer you have: "; Off; ", it means that space characters are obligatory aswell, what if it is the last STATUS? will it have character ";" and " "?

Comment: @GabriT. I added semi-colons and spaces in my concat, and according to the OP, there is a space in when the field contains multiple items. It can be changed if necessary.